# In c# is it possible to pass or return operators like types

Tags: c#

I have an excel exporter class that must take filtering information from a third party and use that info to filter data. The filtering information comes in as strings like "equals", "greatherthan", etc. What is the best way to produce reusable code that can convert these filtering types into c# code.

I was thinking it might be good to convert them into operators and return that. But I don't know if this is possible or even a good idea. What do you think?

Comment: See [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Behavioral_patterns). Of interest could be the Mediator pattern or Proxy patterns.

Comment: I was thinking the Strategy pattern.

Comment: Operators you describe (>, != etc) are just functions that take 2 arguments of the same type and return bool. So you can store them as Func<T,T,bool> delegates (where T is the type of arguments).

Comment: Could you not just search the incoming string for those chars and use a switch statement where a function would be called determined by the char found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  public class ExcelFiltersManager
{
    public static class ExcelFilters
    {
        public const string Equal = "equals";
        public const string GreaterThen = "greaterthan";

        // complete here the other operators.
    }

    static class Operators
    {
        // C# compiler converts overloaded operators to functions with name op_XXXX where XXXX is the opration

        public const string Equality = "op_Equality";
        public const string InEquality = "op_Inequality";
        public const string LessThan = "op_LessThan";
        public const string GreaterThan = "op_GreaterThan";
        public const string LessThanOrEqual = "op_LessThanOrEqual";
        public const string GreaterThanOrEqual = "op_GreaterThanOrEqual";
    }

    public bool GetOperatorBooleanResult<T>(string excelFilter, T value1, T value2)
    {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(T).GetMethod(GetOperatorCompileName(excelFilter), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        return (bool)mi.Invoke(null, new object[] { value1, value2 });
    }

    private string GetOperatorCompileName(string excelFilter)
    {
        string operatorCompileName = string.Empty;

        switch (excelFilter)
        {
            case ExcelFilters.Equal:
                operatorCompileName = Operators.Equality;
                break;
            case ExcelFilters.GreaterThen:
                operatorCompileName = Operators.GreaterThan;
                break;

                // continue here the mapping with the rest of operators
        }

        return operatorCompileName;
    }
}
```

then in your code you can use the following to get the result of the filter:

```
decimal value1 = 5;
decimal value2 = 10;

bool result = GetOperatorBooleanResult(ExcelFilters.GreaterThen, value1, value2);
```

Comment: Hmm. This is interesting I did not know that internally operators have a string name. Let me see some of the other suggestions, but this looks promising. Thanks.